# Accessing UICollectionViewCell's UICollectionView in its awakeFromNib method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to access the UICollectionView to which a UICollectionViewCell belongs to in the UICollectionViewCell's awakeFromNib method. When I try to use the following code:

> self.superview!

I receive the following error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Stuff like this is bad practice. Update your question with what do you want to accomplish, and there's probably a better solution.

Comment: What I want to do is to have a button inside the cell that its width is proportional to the parent uicollectionview's width.

Comment: Simple solution would be to pass that as a property when the cell is setup in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: That's a great solution, but I am not sure how to send a param value to awakeFromNib!

Comment: Your collectionViewCell has no idea who is its collectionView. It's not part of chain responder either. You need an approach like @shim says.

Comment: I think maybe I can have a custom init method for cell to which I send the param and use it in awakeFromNib... Let me try it. Thanks

Comment: Set a custom property on your cell subclass. When you set the property in your view controller subclass, adjust the views (i.e. write a custom setter for the property). You don't need to do this for every single cell if you don't have to, because the cells are reused. (ie check if cell has not been set up)

Answer (score -1):

It would be simplest to pass these properties through the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: UICollectionViewCell doesn't provides such api